# What can I assume about Mandelstam variables in four-photon scattering?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, quantum-electrodynamics

In the case of four-photon scattering, the Mandelstam variables must satisfy

$s+t+u=0$

Where:

$
s=-(p_1+p_2)^2, t=-(p_1+p_3)^2, u=-(p_1+p_4)^2
$

And we know that $s>0$ is true because it is the total energy squared. What can I assume for $t$ and $u$? Are they free to be one negative and the other positive and viceversa? Or is there a restriction over their possible values?

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly Peskin & Schroeder derive some more general properties:

1. $\qquad s > 0 \qquad, \qquad t \le 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad u\le 0 $
2. $\qquad t=0$ for $\theta =0$ and $u=0$ for $\theta = \pi\;$ ($\theta$ being the scattering angle)
3. $\qquad s\ge |t|$